# How to make Fisher's exact test plural

Tags: grammatical-number

How would I say the plural form of "Fisher's exact test". Would it be "Fisher exact tests?".

Here's a  fragment:

We also compared different groups using "Fisher Exact Tests".

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The plural of *test* is *tests*. The plural of *my test* is *my tests*. The plural of *exact test* is *exact tests*. The plural of *Fisher's test* is *Fisher's tests*. The plural of *your car* is *your cars*. Why would the plural of *your car* be *you cars*? It makes no sense.

Comment: I think this question is wrong!  You used Fisher's Exact Test, but you used it several times.  If you used the same tool several times, it is still just one tool.  The fact that you used it to compare group A to group B, then used it again to compare group C to Group D, doesn't mean you used two different tests, you used the same test or tool twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plural of "test" is "tests." The plural of "blue test" is "blue tests." The plural of "Fisher's exact test" is "Fisher's exact tests."

In English, to pluralize a noun modified by an adjective or adjective phrase, you pluralize the noun and leave the adjective or adjective phrase as is. The only time this is confusing is when the adjective follows the noun, as in "attorneys general" or "sons in law."

Comment: This is precisely right. And of course the confusing exceptions are neither confusing nor exceptions. In noun phrases, the head noun gets pluralized. Wherever it happens to be in the phrase. Modifiers do not get pluralized, they are mere modifiers aka red herrings.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is only one Fisher's Exact Test, even if you use it several times.  Like using other tools, say a hammer, that fact you used it several times doesn't magically make it plural.  It is still just one tool.